# Why does the exception not get me in the catch block?

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to interrogate some service information. Sometimes the installer of the application fails to correctly install, so the registry does not contain a service entry. I want to find out which installer steps did get executed correctly, even on systems that do not have proper logging in the installer.

If `MyService` does not exist, the script below does not go to the `catch` block even though the [exception handling documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-4.0) suggests a bare `catch` should be enough:

```
try {
    $path = 'hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MyService'
    $key = Get-Item $path
    $namevalues = $key | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property |
        ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Name = $_;
            Value = $key.GetValue($_)
        }
    }
    $namevalues | Format-Table
}
catch {
    $ProgramFilesX86 = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("ProgramFilesX86");
    $ProgramFiles = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("ProgramFiles");
    Write-Host $ProgramFilesX86
    Write-Host $ProgramFiles
}
```

Why is that and how should I force it to end up in the `catch`?

This is what PowerShell outputs:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MyService' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Developer\...\GetMyServiceInfo.ps1:17 char:12
+     $key = Get-Item $path
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SYSTEM\Cu...vices\MyService:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Force the error to be terminating:

```
$key = Get-Item $path -ErrorAction Stop
```

That way it will throw and catch will get it.

Explanation and links to the official Microsoft documentation:

- [`-ErrorAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-erroractioncontinue--ignore--inquire--silentlycontinue--stop--suspend-) is a [Common Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) that can be applied to any PowerShell command
- The default value for `-ErrorAction` is `Continue` which prevented the exception to be thrown in the first place.
- You can configure a global `-ErrorAction` setting using the [Preference Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables) named [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#erroractionpreference) to override this default value.

Comment: Thanks, +1. Please add some links to `-ErrorAction` and `$ErrorActionPreference` documentation. Then I will also accept the answer.

Comment: [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1)